# AWS ElasticBeanstalk NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i want to use ElasticBeanstalk with the predefined configuration "Node.js" and "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9". The problem is that my NodeJS application use gm which need GraphicsMagick, but GrpahicsMagick isn't installed on the predefined configuration! Is it possible to tell Amazon AWS to install missing package after bootstrap and before deploying of my NodeJS application? Which other possibilities I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think i found the answer. Create a file .config in .elasticbeanstalk folder and add following lines `packages: 
  yum:
    ImageMagick: []`
So AWS install the package on each ec2 node. [customize-containers-format-packages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages)

Comment: You should accept you answer by clicking on the tick if this is the right one!

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html) I'd recommend you to put the *.config* file inside a *.ebextensions* directory at the top level of your project.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution which should work as well. Create a `package.config` in `.ebextensions` directory. And state:

```
commands:
  01-command:
    command: yum install -y [option flags] GraphicsMagick
```

Thanks to this answer: [How to install GraphicsMagick on Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33967404/3781320)