# How do I test if an installed global package is working in Elastic Beanstalk running Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, graphicsmagick

I'm using ssh to try to debug why GraphicsMagick isn't working. "node -v" and "ng version" both are unrecognized commands when I know those have to be installed for the app to work, and the app definitely works. So, what's the deal? How do I test if graphics magick is installed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk provides compiled instances for you. The actual node package is located in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install`

GraphicsMagick is not a pre-installed package in the Elastic Beanstalk instances and you will need to install it yourself using `.ebextensions`

You'd need to create a file in your codebase like: `.ebextensions/graphicsmagick.config` with the following contents:

```
commands:
  01-command:
    command: yum install -y --enablerepo=epel GraphicsMagick
```

Reference: [Graphicsmagick not working in Elastic Beanstalk with nodejs and S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571394/graphicsmagick-not-working-in-elastic-beanstalk-with-nodejs-and-s3)

Comment: so I tried this and it still doesn't work. I would like to know if it worked or not. Is there a definitive way of knowing whether it was installed or not? I can't find anything in the logs.

Comment: You can run `yum list installed` I believe you do have to invoke a manual deploy using the versions interface for the `.ebextensions` to be recompiled.